# Pls how can i redirect a page using Vanilla Javascript when the browser back button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, vanilla-forums

This is what I came up with, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function prev() {window.history.forward(); window.location.href = 'google.com';} 
setTimeout(prev(), 0); window.onunload = function() { null }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, but you can warn users using `window.onbeforeunload` that they are gonna navigate back. This might not work in Opera though.

Comment: How do i accomplish that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event